# Did modularity of basic programming first appear with visual basic?

Tags: module, basic

Modularity of basic programming first appeared with visual basic? True or False?

Comment: Depending on your definition of modularity, I'm quite sure it's false.

Comment: Are you talking about modules in versions of BASIC, or in all languages?

Comment: modules in BASIC programming.. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

False, even GW Basic & Quick Basic which have appeared before visual basic have modularity.

Answer (score 3):

**False**  - Gordon Eubanks product: **CBasic** (written aboard USS George Washington) first available from IMSAI then later from Digital Research Corp after they bought it circa 1981 see [this entry on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBASIC) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

QBasic (and presumably QuickBasic) had subroutines and functions which were (or at least could be) viewed and edited separately from the main program.  While not file-level modularity, that does stand as one example.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen examples of clean, modular BASIC code that predate VB. In general, you can use any programming approach with any syntax, although some syntaxes encourage a particular style. The BASIC language is free-form enough that the style it tends to encourage is "messy". Over the years Microsoft has made an effort to introduce features in VB that promote more structure.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft's BASIC PDS 7.1 compiler (Professional Development System) from 1989ish was very modular.  You could link in C routines & Assembly routines (and Fortran IIRC).  And the Basic itself allowed for calling other BASIC routines as sub-routines ect.  I still use it today.

Comment: This does not answer `Did modularity of Basic programming first appear with Visual Basic?`

Comment: OK, it is FALSE for the reasons I listed in my fist  reply.

Comment: Assuming *fis**r**t reply* intended, what *is* that reply? This one is the only SO post with [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20206504/aoresteen). And don't put essential contents in comments. Edit the post, replicating (non stack**overflow**/StackExchange contents) where hyperlinking.